# Does office.js support the shapes collection?

Tags: office-js, shapes

Is the "shapes" collection supported in office.js?  If so, how do I iterate around it?  Below is the equivalent C# code I'm trying to achieve in office.js

```
foreach (Word.Shape shape in document.Shapes)
{
   if (shape.Type == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox)
   {
       string shapeText = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on some quick research I would conclude that the 'Shapes' property as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.shapes), is not available in the Office.js Word API. The Office.js Word API only allows to interact with a very select subset of objects in the document. Objects that can be retrieved and might be relevant to you are:

- [Rich text content controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=office-js)
- [Inline pictures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.inlinepicture?view=office-js)

Drawings, floating pictures, Active X controls, shapes, and others are not supported at the moment. You could try to retrieve these objects by parsing the OOXML. The [Office.js Excel API Beta](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs#whats-new-in-the-excel-javascript-beta) does seem to support shapes. This could mean that the functionality you require will find its way to the Office.js Word API in time.